# Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

> Let $f$ be  a function in $(0,\infty)$ such that $f'(x)$ exists.
> In addition, $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f'(x)=L$ (**finite**) and $f(n)=0$ for every $n \in \Bbb N$.
>
> Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=0$

I think Rolle's theorem might help here, but I don't know how to use it.

Any hints are most welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: using Rolles can select a sequence $c_n$ where $n<c_n<n+1$ and $f'(c_n)=0.$ This follows since $f(n)=f(n+1)$ (both are zero by your assumption). So whatever the limit of $f'(x)$ is, there is a subseqence of that converging to $0.$

Comment: You mean $f'(c_n) = 0$.

Comment: @EduardoLonga Yes, typed to fast. Thanks, will fix.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** [Mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) in $[n,n+1]$ says that there exists a $c_n\in [n,n+1]$ such that $$f'(c_n)=\frac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{n+1-n}=0$$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$.